# Return "None" in the case there is no valid result for any combination of the supplied variables

Tags: python, expression, prefix

I am trying to solve a prefix expression. I want to return None whenever I encounter an invalid prefix expression or if the expression does not have any valid result. The expression is input as a string.

For Example:

```
expression: -+1 5 3
value: "None"

expression: + 1
value: "None"
```

My logic to do this is:

```
    if (expression[-1] in ops or expression [-2] in ops ):#is this correct?
        return "None"
```

ops contains {+,-,*,/}

**How do I do this?**

Edit:

```
ops={
    "+":add,
    "-":sub,
    "*":mul,
    "/":div
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more your question, what is the ops variable, is it some kind of a structure that contains valid expressions ?

Comment: @Stefanc check edit.

Comment: `None` is not the same thing as the string `"None"`.  You've also given examples of "invalid" input, but not "valid" input, so based on the samples you've given it seems like the easy answer is to just put `return None` at the start of the function.

Answer (score 0):

None is a data type but you return a `"None"` string not `None` data, omit quotes also i couldn't understand input but if it is an integer; integers are not iterable so you can't slice them

Comment: the input is a string

Comment: @SharinSung anyway i don't think it will handle all conditions but it seems ok for the 2 expressions you gave

Answer (score 0):

Your `ops` is a dictionary, where you've got operations as keys.

```
if expressions not in ops:
   return None
```

This will return `None` when it can't find your `expressions` within the keys of your dictionary `ops`

Hope this is what you meant.